# css-menu not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new version of a website. Right now I am almost satisfied with the results, except one problem. The website consists of a header (with logo and menu) and a content-part. I want it to work on both larg/small-size screens.

On a small screen I encounter one problem. When I expand the menu it is on top of the content-part, but the content-part is still clickable, so the menu-options are not clickable and the menu is not working right.

What I want is as follows (for small screen, i.e. Smartphone):
- When I click 'Show Menu' all menu-options will show up (Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4) and are clickable. Underlying text (div 'page') not visible (dissapears under the menu-options).
- When I click one of the menu-options, all options in submenu will show up and are clickable. Underlying text (div 'page') not visible.

I already searched and tried many options, but not with the expected result.

Thanks in advance for any hints :)

My html is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="#" style="width:180px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1 &#65516;</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2 &#65516;</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu23</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3 &#65516;</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu31</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu32</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu33</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4 &#65516;</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu41</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu42</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu43</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu44</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu45</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu46</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
      <h3>Header</h3><hr>
    </div>
    <div id="pageliquid">
      <div id="page">Page-text<br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #001245;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

#menu {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

#header {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

#pageliquid {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

#page {
  top: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}

ul, img {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
  display:block;
  min-width:200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0b0b3b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #0b0b3b;
}

li:hover ul a {
  background: #08088a;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #08088a;
  color: #ffffff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

li ul li a {
  width: 160px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  #wrapper {
    min-width: 0px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #header {
    position: absolute;
  }

  #page {
    left: 0px;
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

  ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
  }

  li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
   padding: 0 0px;
  }

  .show-menu {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot going on there that we have to imagine. Your question might be clearer and easy to solve if you posted a demo or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the z-index of the menu since it is underneath later elements on the page due to the fixed height and natural height of `#menu` and absolute positioning of that menu. You have duplicate ID's here, but forcing a higher `z-index` on `#menu` puts the navigation above other elements on the page. That also requires changing `position: static;` to `position: relative;` on `#menu` as well. Here's a demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJwoOL (PS - there were some overlapping issues with your nested `li`'s and `ul`'s that I tweaked a little in your media query, too, but are unrelated to your question here)